# rvm install 2.7.8 'there was an error installing gem rubygems-bundler'

Tags: ruby, rvm

Im on Ububtu 22.04.  I have a system working at ruby 2.7.1 Rails 5.2.8.1.   I'm trying to update ruby to 2.7.8

2.7.1 was NOT installed using rvm

I've installed rvm and I'm running

rvmsudo rvm install 2.7.8

And it fails.

```
Found remote file https://rubies.travis-ci.org/ubuntu/22.04/x86_64/ruby-2.7.8.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
ruby-2.7.8 - #configure
ruby-2.7.8 - #download
ruby-2.7.8 - #validate archive
ruby-2.7.8 - #extract
ruby-2.7.8 - #validate binary
ruby-2.7.8 - #setup
ruby-2.7.8 - #gemset created /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.8@global
ruby-2.7.8 - #importing gemset /usr/share/rvm/gemsets/global.gems
...............there was an error installing gem gem-wrappers
.................there was an error installing gem rubygems-bundler
...............there was an error installing gem rake
................there was an error installing gem rvm
................there was an error installing gem bundler
..
```

There are other errors later but these seem to be the cause of my problems.

So the 'current' Ruby 2.7.1 installation is not an rvm one - I dont know if that makes any difference.  In either case 2.7.8 is NOT installed, even though I can

`rvm use ruby-2.7.8 --default`

But then, obviously everything goes to rats because 2.7.8 isnt installed

Any ideas greatfully received

Comment: How was 2.7.1 installed?

Comment: So if you do `ruby -v` what do you get? Having other rubies installed shouldn't matter to RVM because it's always worked with ignoring system installed rubies. Also are you attached to RVM? I switched to rbenv and find it much easier than RVM. Just a thought.